# Query XML param inside XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters

I have XSLT, where I have defined param 'secondXml', which could have XML value, something like

```
<test>123</test>
```

Is it possible to perform some queries against that parameter? I tried with below example, but it didnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="secondXml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:value-of select="$secondXml/test"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: You will need to tell and show us exactly which XSLT processor you use and which API you use to set the parameter. Also why does the title say "XSLT 1.0" and the code has `version="2.0"`?

Comment: Ah, sorry about the version, it is copy/pasted. The reason is that i have to use only 1.0 functionalities. I found possible solution by converting the param value into a node-set and quering it.. but most probably i will search for some simple solution.. probably wrapping both XML-s in a same wrapper and applying XSLT over it.

Comment: The type of paramters you can pass to an XSLT processor and how types of the host language or platform (e.g. .NET framework, Java, PHP) are mapped to XPath and/or XSLT types depends entirely on the particular XSLT processor you use and the API it exposes to the host language or framework.